# How do I remove extra line at the end of my nested for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-loops

With input 2, my code outputs:

```
0
 1
  2
(whitespace)
```

I have tried changing my loop conditions but I'm confused.

I want to remove the whitespace, here is my code:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int userNum;
    int i;
    int j;

    cin >> userNum;

    char space = ' ';

    for (i = 0; i <= userNum; i++)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout << space;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Print the whitespace _before_ you call  `cout << i << endl;`?

Comment: *Don't* "print `i` and a newline, then the appropriate number of spaces for the next line"; *do* "print the appropriate number of spaces for this line, then `i` and a newline". (That is, focus on just one line at a time.)

Comment: To print `n` spaces you could do: `std::cout << std::string(n, ' ');`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to print n spaces before the nth occurrence, modify the for loop as

```
for (i = 0; i <= userNum; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            cout << space;
        }
        cout << i << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove that pesky line down there, you could use a condition:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int userNum;
    int i;
    int j;

    cin >> userNum;

    char space = ' ';

    for (i = 0; i <= userNum; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            cout << space;
        }
        cout << i;
        if (i != userNum) {cout << endl;} //only go to next line if not reached final line

    }
}
```

Output:

```
4
0
 1
  2
   3
    4
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need is to move cout code in the first for loop, after nested for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i <= userNum; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        cout << space;
    }
    cout << i << endl;
}
```